# Spark org.postgresql.Driver not found even though it's configured EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to write a pyspark data frame to a Postgres database with the following code:

```
mode = "overwrite"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://host/database"
properties = {"user": "user","password": "password","driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
dfTestWrite.write.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o236.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I've found a few SO questions that address a similar issue but haven't found anything that helps. I followed the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/presto-adding-db-connectors.html) to add the configuration and from the EMR console it looks as though it was successful:

[image: EMR Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you followed document is to add the database connector for the Presto and it is not a way to add the jdbc driver into the spark. Connector does not mean the driver.

You should download the postgresql jdbc driver and locate it to the spark lib directory or somewhere to refer it by a configuration.

Comment: --jars will ensure that extra jars that are not part of Spark, or your app jar will be shipped to the cluster

Comment: @Lamanus thanks, I've downloaded the jar, stored it on S3 and am trying to attach it to the cluster when I configure it but it keeps failing. Could you go into a little more detail about how to do that?

Comment: Not on the s3. It should be in the server.